# VSCode does not recognize typescript 3.7.2 features

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code 1.40.0 and i have the following `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "test",
  "main": "./src/main.ts",
  "sideEffects": false,  
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.6.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.6.1",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "typescript": "^3.7.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
  }
}
```

And the following `tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": [
            "es2019",
            "dom",
            "es2019.array"
        ],
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "es6",
        "strict": true,
        "strictBindCallApply": true,
        "strictFunctionTypes": true,
        "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true
    }
}
```

But when writing the following code `const a = null ?? 0;` vscode complains, but when compiling it works as intended, so is there some setting that must be changed to allow vscode to to parse Typescript 3.7 correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing [JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-next) solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following to your settings so it uses the TypeScript in your node_modules instead of its built-in one (which is probably still on 3.6):

```
"typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib"
```

Comment: In what file do you want me to add this line?

Comment: In your main settings file of VSCode or in `yourproject/.vscode/settings.json` if you only want it to apply to that project.